# Error: Unexpected end of JSON input in npm install after running jhipster command

Tags: node.js, npm, jhipster

I have node v: 10.15.0, npm v: 6.4.11
and I'm trying to install JHipster. the files generation worked fine but when it runs `npm install` I got this error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....0.2","null-loader":"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chiheb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-07T21_05_15_281Z-debug.log
```

this is the end of the log file:

```
2606 silly saveTree pharma-care@0.0.0
2606 silly saveTree +-- @angular/common@7.1.0
2606 silly saveTree | `-- tslib@1.9.3
2606 silly saveTree +-- @angular/compiler@7.1.0
2606 silly saveTree +-- @angular/core@7.1.0
2606 silly saveTree +-- @angular/forms@7.1.0
2606 silly saveTree +-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@7.1.0
2606 silly saveTree +-- @angular/platform-browser@7.1.0
2606 silly saveTree +-- @angular/router@7.1.0
2606 silly saveTree +-- @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.3.0
2606 silly saveTree +-- @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.2.8
2606 silly saveTree +-- @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@5.5.0
2606 silly saveTree +-- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@4.0.0
2606 silly saveTree +-- bootstrap@4.1.3
2606 silly saveTree +-- core-js@2.5.7
2606 silly saveTree +-- moment@2.22.2
2606 silly saveTree +-- ng-jhipster@0.5.6
2606 silly saveTree +-- ngx-cookie@2.0.1
2606 silly saveTree +-- ngx-infinite-scroll@6.0.1
2606 silly saveTree +-- ngx-webstorage@2.0.1
2606 silly saveTree +-- rxjs@6.3.3
2606 silly saveTree +-- tslib@1.9.3
2606 silly saveTree `-- zone.js@0.8.26
2607 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....0.2","null-loader":"'
2607 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2607 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
2607 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
2607 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
2608 verbose cwd E:\education\ENISo\IA3.2\ProjetSemestriel\PharmaCare
2609 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
2610 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--cache-min" "86400"
2611 verbose node v10.15.0
2612 verbose npm  v6.4.1
2613 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....0.2","null-loader":"'
2614 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I think the problem is in the package.json file generated by Jhipster but I couldn't find the mistake in it.
package.json:

```
{
"name": "pharma-care",
"version": "0.0.0",
"description": "Description for PharmaCare",
"private": true,
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
],
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "7.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.8",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.5.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.5.6",
    "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "6.0.1",
    "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
    "tslib": "1.9.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "7.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "7.0.6",
    "@types/jest": "23.3.9",
    "@types/node": "10.12.10",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.8.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "autoprefixer": "9.3.1",
    "browser-sync": "2.26.3",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.2.2",
    "cache-loader": "1.2.5",
    "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.7.0",
    "generator-jhipster": "5.7.2",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "husky": "1.2.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-junit": "5.2.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "6.0.1",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "8.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.5",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "1.0.7",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "prettier": "1.15.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2",
    "simple-progress-webpack-plugin": "1.1.2",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "thread-loader": "1.2.0",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "5.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.16.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.6.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.19",
    "webpack": "4.26.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.10",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.4",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.7.0",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.5.0"
},
"engines": {
    "node": ">=8.9.0"
},
"lint-staged": {
    "{,src/**/}*.{md,json,ts,css,scss}": [
        "prettier --write",
        "git add"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "prettier:format": "prettier --write \"{,src/**/}*.{md,json,ts,css,scss}\"",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/{aot,www}",
    "clean-www": "rimraf target//www/app/{src,target/}",
    "start": "npm run webpack:dev",
    "start-tls": "npm run webpack:dev -- --env.tls",
    "serve": "npm run start",
    "build": "npm run webpack:prod",
    "test": "npm run lint && jest --coverage --logHeapUsage -w=2 --config src/test/javascript/jest.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "webpack:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal",
    "webpack:dev-verbose": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --profile --progress --env.stats=normal",
    "webpack:build:main": "npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env.stats=minimal",
    "webpack:build": "npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:build:main",
    "webpack:prod:main": "npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile",
    "webpack:prod": "npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www",
    "webpack:test": "npm run test",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
},
"jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "target/test-results/jest",
    "reportFile": "TESTS-results-sonar.xml"
}
}
```

so I hope that you find a solution to this problem because it took me so long to open this question.

Comment: What version of jhipster are you using? Have you added some npm dependencies already?

Comment: I use Jhipster v 5.7.2. No, I did not.

Comment: I struggled with how to install firebase-tools as npm gave me the same error.Jose Castillo's answer worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error, I fixed running npm cache clean --force

Comment: This solution works for the same error I got while installing Firebase CLI. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g lodash
```

fixed it for me
https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/14#issuecomment-249326651